# cache issue on custom block

Tags: magento2

The `FPC` is turned off in admin, product page is not cache, I have tested all attribute and its working when i edit a content.

But on my custom block every time I change a value in my custom table in the database its not showing in product page unless i clear static cache in admin.

My problem is my custom block is always caching.

FPC is turned off in admin product page is not cache test all attribute its working when i edit a content but on my custom block every time i change a value in my custom table in the database its not showing in product page unless i clear static cache in admin.

Tried all possible solution ive seen in s.o

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 cache can be disabled but when you apply any change in your custom table of attribute or do any change in custom template you need to refresh cache.

It also depends on **browser cache** so you should test your module in private browser.

For removing cache or disable cache you can refer [click](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html)

Comment: Waah bhai improvement ...... Magento 2 aavdi gayu.